# Show color thresholds in c3.js gauge

Tags: javascript, c3.js, gauge

I'm trying to configure a [c3](/questions/tagged/c3)gauge chart but I would like to show the threshold values in the chart (outside labels with the color would be nice) just to realize how far the value is from the next level.

Any one can help me?

This is the gauge now:

[image: Gauge Now]

This is what I expect:

[image: Wished gauge]

Comment: Hard to know what you're wanting from that question. Could you rephrase/elaborate?

Answer (score 7):

There is no specific option in **c3.js** Gauge chart to draw thresholds lines and legends, so I thought to use **d3.js** to add them to chart on `rendered` event:

```
onrendered: function() {
    drawThresholds(this, thresholdOpts, opts);
}
```

Check this jsfiddle for complete example: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/032tcczg/

Output obtained looks like below:

[image]

and:

[image]

Comment: @Martina, Is this proposal suitable for you?